# Import instance from MEF container imperatively in code in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mef

I'm using MEF in my Silverlight application. My code would be a lot cleaner if there were a way to "import" an instance imperatively in code (i.e. without using the `Import` attribute). I've been using MEF for quite some time and I have the declarative side of MEF down.

**Edits:**

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
var myObject = container.Import<MyType>();
```

Comment: MEF2 (.NET 4.5) adds a new model called Conventions. Have a look at this series of articles (the one on "Fluent import" shows what you are looking for) for an introduction: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2013/01/06/mef-2-0-toc.aspx

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I'm kind of wanting to do something Unity like as in the edits above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just new up the object you want and use [CompositionInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.compositioninitializer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to satisfy any MEF dependencies in the class you are getting.  This is what I do anyways :)  Here's [another short article](http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/02/prism-4-mef-and-the-compositioninitializer/) on this using WPF, but I think the use is the same or very similar in silverlight.

Comment: Ok, I guess I should have been more clear. In this case, I don't want to use a public property or constructor parameter. I want to get it imperatively not declaratively. I know how `CompositionInitializer` works. I guess I can't do what I want to do with MEF. This is why I've rolled my own IOC in my other projects. Nothing is more extensible than custom code.

Comment: Yep, MEF doesn't provide what you are looking for, although I have to admit I don't see the distinction you are making- maybe you can describe how using the CompositionInitializer in this way isn't imperative? But there's also no reason why you shouldn't use Unity to do this- Unity and MEF in the same project is fine.

Comment: I just don't like having public properties sitting there when I only use them for one small part of my object code. I'd like to use MEF in private if you know what I mean.

Comment: I know, i can use Unity and MEF together, but having two different containers is a little messy. I just don't like how MEF requires one to "pollute" one's public interface with import properties.